# Перебор всех блоков - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здраствуйте , мне надо перебрать все блоки которые есть на странице в `body` все дочерние блоки.
Как я могу это сделать ?

```
<body>
   <div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
   </div>
   <p>some text <span>3</span><p>
</body>
```

```js
$("body").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).css("background"));
});
//проблема в том что это-т скрипт не заходит в дочерние элементы , а мне надо перебрать все элементы страницы.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации метод `each()` выполняет итерацию по объекту jQuery, выполняя при этом функцию на каждом СОПОСТОВИМОМ элементе. В вашем случае таким элементом является `body`. Чтобы пройтись по ВСЕМ дочерним элементам можно использовать метод `children()` у объекта `$('body')`. А чтобы выбрать интересующие вас элементы (те же `<div></div>`, `<p></p>`) можно попробовать код ниже:

```js
$('body').children('div, p').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "#000",
    "color": "#fff"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>1
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>2.1
        <div>2.1.1</div>
        <div>2.1.2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <p>some text <span>3</span>
    <p>
</body>
```

Comment: на странице будет много дочерних елементов , и много вложений , это-т код разве сможет перебрать их все ?

Comment: Изменил структуру html - можете увидеть результат

Comment: Этот код соберёт даже такие теги как `<script>`, `<link>` и прочие. ВСЁ соберёт, но не текстовые узлы

Comment: Для текстовых узлов, помнится, нужен метод `contents()`

Comment: И ещё вопрос по тому что вы указали `('body').children('div, p')` , мне надо все возможные теги получить , в css есть `*` тут я так полагаю можно сделать `('body').children('*')`  да ?

Comment: Можно просто `$('body').children()`

Comment: хорошо спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием `css`

```css
body > * {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>1</div>
   </div>
   <p>some text <span>3</span><p>
</body>
```

Вариант с использованием `js`

```js
const bodyChilds = document.querySelectorAll('body > *');
bodyChilds.forEach(el => el.classList.add('bg'))
```

```css
.bg {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <p>some text <span>3</span><p>
</body>
```

Comment: надо через jQuery так как это тестовый упрощёный код , сама функция должна проверять все блоки и проверять аргументы у них .

Comment: @Igor Biyar - ок, добавил вариант с использованием ```js```, без ```jquery```

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется установить стили, то не обязательно использовать `.each()`.

```js
$('body div, body p').css({
  "background": "#000",
  "color": "#fff"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>1
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>2.1
        <div>2.1.1</div>
        <div>2.1.2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <p>some text <span>3</span>
    <p>
</body>
```